# Getting html tag value in python

Tags: python, html, parsing, tags

I'm newbie to python. Here is my code working on python 2.7.5

```
import urllib2
import sys       

url ="mydomain.com"
usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = usock.read()
usock.close()

print data
```

Getting HTML markup like that and it works.

What I want to do is, to get value from inside `<font class="big"></font>` tag. for ex. I need data value from this example:

```
<font class="big">Data</font>
```

How to do it?

Comment: `font`? Wow, that's really old and evil HTML.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a HTML parser module such as [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
url ="mydomain.com"
usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = usock.read()
usock.close()
soup = BS(data)
print soup.find('font', {'class':'big'}).text
```

This finds a tag `<font>` with a `class="big"`. It then prints its content.

Comment: ImportError: No module named bs4

Comment: @heron It's not in the standard library. Check the link I provided to find a download

Answer (score 1):

Using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de):

```
import urllib2
import lxml.html

url ="mydomain.com"

usock = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = usock.read()
usock.close()
for font in lxml.html.fromstring(data).cssselect('font.big'):
    print font.text
```

---

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> root = lxml.html.fromstring('<font class="big">Data</font>')
>>> [font.text for font in root.cssselect('font.big')]
['Data']
```